# $\mathcal{Z}\models \phi(13)$ if and only if $\mathcal{Z}\models\phi(-13)$

Tags: first-order-logic

Consider the structure $\mathcal{Z}=(\mathbb{Z},0,+,-)$ in the language of abelian groups $\mathcal{L}_{ab}=(0,+,-)$. we want to show that $\mathcal{Z}\models \phi(13)$ if and only if $\mathcal{Z}\models\phi(-13)$

I don't know how to proceed. do we do it by induction on the complexity of the formula $\phi$?

Comment: Do you know that isomorphisms preserve satisfaction of formulas? Can you find an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}$ mapping $13$ to $-13$?

Comment: Altering the identity of $\mathbb{Z}$ by mapping 13 to -13 and -13 to 13 ?

Comment: That's not an isomorphism, because $f(12+1) = f(13) = -13$, but $f(12)+f(1) = 12 + 1 = 13$.

Comment: i think that $f(n)=-n$ should work ? im i right ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f(n) = -n$ is an automorphism of $\mathcal{Z}$. Since isomorphisms preserve satisfaction of formulas, for any formula $\varphi(x)$, $\mathcal{Z}\models \varphi(13)$ if and only if $\mathcal{Z}\models \varphi(f(13))$ if and only if $\mathcal{Z}\models \varphi(-13)$.